# What does "hardware register set" mean in ACPI?

Tags: operating-system, firmware, uefi, acpi

I am reading [an ACPI Introduction doc](https://acpica.org/sites/acpica/files/ACPI-Introduction.pdf). It says:

> ACPI can first be understood as an architecture­ independent power
>   management and configuration framework that forms a subsystem within
>   the host OS. This framework establishes **a hardware register set to
>   define power states (sleep, hibernate, wake, etc).** The hardware
>   register set can accommodate operations on dedicated hardware and
>   general purpose hardware.

I don't quite understand the bold part about the **register set**.

My current understanding is, all devices on a platform have registers on themselves to provide controllability. Does ACPI collect all the registers from all devices and use the status of these registers to describe/control the platform? In other words, ACPI sees the platform as nothing but a set of registers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some reading about the [ACPI Spec 6.0](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjRtLDN_L3OAhVBTWMKHX6RBxUQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.uefi.org%2Fsites%2Fdefault%2Ffiles%2Fresources%2FACPI_6.0.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGUWdQ8KH1ksLLrCjcRRM2K8RfWHw&sig2=e2eYon3gTqcOgJ07VkI-2Q), I came to this:

ACPI is an interface implementation of the OSPM (Operating System-directed motherboard device configuration and Power Management).

The purpose of OSPM is to **shift and centralize** the Power Management and Device Configuration capabilities into the Operating System for more robust and sophisticated management.

The purpose of ACPI is to **standardize** the OSPM implementation.

Such capabilities used to be scattered among applications, system BIOS, and hardware, etc. And quite often propriety implementations. Once such capabilities are integrated into an OS, applications for that OS will benefit from a bunch of new interfaces/APIs to configure the device and manipulate the power.

To achieve such goal, besides software endeavors, hardware must be designed to facilitate OSPM/ACPI. And certain ACPI-compatible registers must be incorporated. I think this is the register-set in my question.

However, hardware designer who hails the OSPM rational, doesn't necessarily have to follow the ACPI, after all, ACPI is just one way to achieve OSPM. If hardware designer choose to be OSPM-compatible but not ACPI-compatible, he has to provide his own drivers for the target OS.

Answer (score 0):

No, it means that ACPI have registers to provide controllability - the same understanding you have for other devices.

What controllability? It's mentioned in the quote: to allow you to put the device to sleep, hibernate, wake-up etc.

What device? It depends on the platform but for the PC it's the motherboard itself (or rather, the memory bridges on the motherboard which is mostly integrated into the CPU itself these days).